# Slick slider jumps

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, slick.js

I am using *slick slider* for a page.Everything works great except one thing: When I drag the slide sometimes the image or text bounces and that's look really bad. What can I do to avoid that problem?

Here is my [code](https://codepen.io/elene/pen/GZwgQL)

```
  <section class="portfolio" id="portfolio">

        <div class="container" style="height:100px">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
                <div id="portfolio_slider">
                    <div id="item">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 text-right">
                                    <div id="project_name">
                                        PROJECT<br />
                                        NAME
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="project-info">
                                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec tortor erat,
                                        laoreet ut ullamcorper vel, fermentum vel ex. Donec convallis leo sit amet auctor
                                        rutrum. Nullam accumsan risus at quam porttitor ec tortor erat, laoreet ut
                                        ullamcorper vel, fermentum vel  tristique.
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="read_more"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal">Read More...</a></div>

                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-7 col-lg-offset-1" id="project_image">
                                    <img class="img-responsive shadow" src="http://i.imgur.com/35Lun7R.jpg" />

                                </div>
                                <div class=" col-lg-1 col-md-1  social_buttons">
                                    <div class="centered">
                                        <div class="flex-item" style="padding-bottom: 50px;">
                                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="flex-item" style="padding-bottom: 50px;">
                                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="flex-item">
                                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
   </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score -1):

in the code pen, in CSS, there is one class, `#portfolio_slider #item` with `margin: top 20px` remove it.